# iphone - Authorization Post petition

Tags: iphone, post, http-authentication

I am trying to make an user authorization to webservice in iphone. The equivalent ant test java version is the  following code:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://webserviceurl/authuser");

    // Header Basic  base64 user:pass
    post.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +   Base64.encodeBase64String(StringUtils.getBytesUtf8("myuser:mypassword")));

    // FIELD
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario", "doxsi@doxsi.com"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass"));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
```

How can make the same by objective-c?
My solutios is:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://webserviceurl/authuser";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSString *userName = @"myuser";
NSString *password = @"mypass";

NSError *myError = nil;

// create a plaintext string in the format username:password
NSMutableString *loginString = (NSMutableString*)[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, password];

// employ the Base64 encoding above to encode the authentication tokens
NSString *encodedLoginData = [Base64 encode:[loginString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// create the contents of the header
NSString *authHeader = [@"Basic " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", encodedLoginData];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url
                                                   cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval: 5];


// add the header to the request.
[request addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

// perform the reqeust
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection
                sendSynchronousRequest: request
                returningResponse: &response
                error: &myError];

// webserver's response.
NSString *result = [Base64 base64StringFromData:data length:64];
```

" encode" and " base64StringFromData" are methods of an externals class Base64 (as here [link1](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/basic_authentication_iphone_cocoa_touch))

Is my code right? 
How can I get the server response?
And How I can implement the java "FIELD"?

Any suggestions is really appreciated. Tx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved and I want to post it if someone havethe same needed.

My code is:

```
    -(IBAction)buttonEntra:(id)sender{

        NSLog(@"starting autorization");
        NSString *urlString = @"http://sytes.net:8080/rest/checkuser";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        NSString *serverName = @"serverUSER";
        NSString *serverPassword = @"serverPASS";

        // create a plaintext string in the format username:password
        NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", serverName, serverPassword];

        NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [Base64 encode:authData ]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url
                                                               cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                           timeoutInterval: 10];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:authValue  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

        //parametros en el body

        NSString *userName = usuario;
        NSString *userPassword = password;

        //esempio doxsi9@hotmail.com - sicignano
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"usuario=%@&password=%@",userName,userPassword];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];


        // perform the reqeust
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *myError = nil;

        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection
                        sendSynchronousRequest: request
                        returningResponse: &response
                        error: &myError];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
    }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    //status code 200 OK   - status code 405 no method defined
    NSLog(@" connection didReceiveResponse: %@", response);

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d {

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"connection didReceiveData: %@",string);

}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Servicio no disponible", @"")
                                message:@"El servidor podria encontrarse en mantenimiento"
                                delegate:nil
                                cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"")
                                otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    // Do anything you want with it
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading ");


}
```

I hope it helps.